# IMACROS subtracting text from extraction

Tags: extract, imacros, subtraction

I'm extracting text from a website:

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=TD ATTR=TXT:*<SP>(View<SP>Listing) EXTRACT=TXT
```

but later i want to use only what is before the VIEW LISTING text so i want to subtract this from the EXTRACT, how to do it?
I tried this:

```
SET !CLIPBOARD {{!EXTRACT}}
ADD !CLIPBOARD -<SP>(View<SP>Public<SP>Listing)
```

and this:

```
SET !EXTRACT EVAL("var s=\"{{!EXTRACT}}\"; s.slice(\"'\", -22);")
```

(found both on stack) but none of these work. also i can't extract without this text in the first place (the site is built this way)

Answer (score 0):

Okay stupid mistake in syntax, found the solution:
SET !EXTRACT EVAL("var s=\"{{!EXTRACT}}\"; s.slice(\"\", -22);")